# gprolog include directive not working

Tags: prolog, gnu-prolog

I am running gprolog version 1.4.2 on a Fedora 17 Linux machine.

I wrote a small prolog program which runs fine. I defined a few predicates in it that I want to hoist out and use in other prolog programs. So I thought I would put them in a separate file and use the `include` directive (defined in sec 7.1.8 of the version 1.4.2 GNU Prolog manual). However, it didn't work. `gprolog` said those predicates (which were in the included file) were undefined.

So at the gprolog prompt I type:

```
| ?- include('tools.pro').
```

And I get:

```
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,include/1),top_level/0
```

So it clearly doesn't recognize the directive. I've searched all over and can't find any reason why this should happen. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified in the ISO Prolog standard, `include/1` is a **directive**, not a **predicate**. GNU Prolog follows the official standard closely, thus you can not use `include/1` as a predicate, including in a top-level query. As Sergey explained, if you want to load your programs, you can use the built-in predicate `consult/1` or its shortcut (`[Fie1, File, ...]`).

To use the include/1 directive in your source files, write it preceded by the `(:-)/1` operator. For example:

```
:- include('tools.pro').
```

Comment: Thanks Paulo. That worked great. I had missed the 'directive' versus 'predicate' description. I just couldn't find an example or explanation how to use it. The only puzzler for me now is what the GNU prolog manual says about it: "If it is not found it is then
searched in each directory of parent includers." I'm not sure what 'parent includers' is referring to.

Comment: You're welcome. Regarding your question regarding the "parent includers", I assume that it refers to scenarios where a file includes a file that, in turn, include other file(s).

Answer (score 0):

`include/1` is for using in Prolog source files.

In the query prompt you probably just want to consult your source file: `['tools.pro'].`

Comment: Thanks. That did occur to me, but I did try compiling the program with the include and it still complained it couldn't find those predicates.

Comment: My original problem was that the include isn't being recognized in a compiled program. I ran it manually at the prompt as a test. Your answer explains why that manual test doesn't work, so I understand that now. But my original problem still exists, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you show your Prolog source file where `include/1` is used?

Comment: I just had it as `include('../tools.pro').` at the top of the file.